# ASPX - what is the path to my folder in web site?

Tags: c#, asp.net, configuration

I have a WebSite project - ASPX, 4.0. In it I have a folder like:

`bin\Xslt\Template.xslt`

I want to load this file in my class library. In web.config is:

```
 <configuration>
    <appSettings>
        <add key="Filepath" value=".\Xslt\Template.xslt" />
    </appSettings>
 </configuration>
```

But, my class library can't find it:

```
 mTransform = new XslCompiledTransform();
 mTransform.Load(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Filepath"]);
```

throws: `Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Xslt\Template.xslt'.`
I know there's a catch here, but I can't remember the proper way...

How to reference a file in an aspx \bin\ folder correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the way (since it's in an assembly and I didn't want to add dependency on System.Web):

```
string codeBase = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase);
string filepathRelative = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Filepath"];

string fullFilepath = Path.Combine(codeBase, filepathRelative);
```

Thanks

**edit**: The `System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory` also does the trick...

Answer (score 1):

Use `Server.Mappath("~\xslt\template.xslt");`

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your key to:

```
<add key="Filepath" value="~/bin/Xslt/Template.xslt" />
```

And change your code to:

```
mTransform.Load(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Filepath"]));
```

Comment: Since this is in a class library, I would like to avoid adding a reference to System.Web...

Answer (score 0):

Try to give the complete path in your web config
Example if your file is at C:\VSPROJECTS\bin\Xslt\Template.xslt

Then in your webconfig write it as
 < add key="Filepath" value="C:\VSPROJECTS\bin\Xslt\Template.xslt" />

Comment: The absolute path will change with deployment to production environment, and I would like to minimize the dependency on deployment specifics...